# Decomposition of Hydrogen Peroxide Catalysed by Potassium Iodide in Basic Solution

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics, ph, decomposition

As part of my high school project, I had to measure the initial rate of decomposition of hydrogen peroxide catalysed by potassium iodide at different pHs. At higher pHs (alkaline conditions), I found the initial rate of reaction to be slower, and I have repeated my experiment multiple times to confirm this. Any possible explanation for these results? I seem to have some trouble finding any answers online. Would appreciate some help on this, thank you!

FYI, I measured initial rate through the volume of gas evolved. There was still gas evolved for high pH, except that the rate was slower

Comment: My blind guess is that in alkaline condition, some of the $\ce{H2O2}$ exists in deprotonated form: $\ce{HO2-}$, and the deprotonated form does not react with iodide($\ce{I-}$). (two anions are unlikely to come close enough for any reaction to occur).